# php repeat array item based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with this:

```
array('adult'  => 2,
      'child'  => 1,
      'infant' => 1);
```

I want the new array to be like this:

```
array([0] => adult,
      [1] => adult,
      [2] => child,
      [3] => infant);
```

Comment: You should really say what you have tried and ask for help on how to sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array('adult'  => 2, 'child'  => 1,'infant' => 1);

$result = [];  // declare variable to store final result
// Loop through array with value and keys 
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
     // Loop again till as per value of the Key
     // Will add that key in final array those many times.
     for ($i=0; $i<$val ; $i++) {
       $result[] = $key;
     }
}

print_r($result);  // will get desired output
```

Comment: Please add some explanations. It would help

Answer (score 2):

This would help also -

```
$arr = array('adult'  => 2, 'child'  => 1,'infant' => 1);

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
   $temp = array_fill(0, $val, $key); // fill array according to value
   $result = array_merge($result, $temp); // merge to original array
}
```

[array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

[Working code](https://eval.in/738148)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a foreach the array and use for loop with it's value

**Step 1 :**

Do a foreach loop with key value pair with your array

```
foreach($cars as $key => $value)
{
  //
}
```

**Step 2 :**

Inside the Foreach loop, do a for loop of it's value

```
for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++)
{
  //
}
```

**Step 3 :**

Assign the `$key` value of the for loop to your newly created array

```
$newArray[] = $key;
```

**Finally**

```
<?php
$cars = array('adult'  => 2,'child'  => 1,'infant' => 1);
$newArray = [];  // Create an Empty Array
foreach($cars as $key => $value)
{
    // Loop through the $value
    for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++)
    {
        $newArray[] = $key;
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Here's the [Eval Link](https://eval.in/738136)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array=array('adult'  => 2,
       'child'  => 1,
       'infant' => 1);
$final_array=[];

     foreach($array as $key=>$value){   

         for($i=0;$i<(int)$value;$i++){
            $final_array[]=$key; 
         }
     }
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($final_array);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => adult
    [1] => adult
    [2] => child
    [3] => infant
)
```